# What does "we're out of clock" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I found something in the movie *The Channel*.

[image: masked guy in military gear with subtitle:]

> Bro, we're out of clock

I know the meaning of that (**we are late, the time is almost finished.**)

But I searched any kinds of dictionary I knew like Oxford dictionary, Merriam Webster, Longman Dictionary, Cambridge Dictionary, Dictionary.com, The Free Dictionary

But I couldn't find anything. (I've also searched (be out of clock/out of the clock)

So is it not a common idiom?
'Cause it wasn't in any kinds of famous dictionary I know.

Can you tell me why I couldn't find that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the page layout is ridiculous!

Comment: I seriously doubt "We're out of clock" has any currency anywhere, but almost certainly it's equivalent to "We're out of **time**" (there is no more time left - we must finish what we're doing immediately).

Comment: Why not prefer the simple edit to a close vote?   I've removed the unnecessary, large  screenshots.

Comment: Thanks Badzen❤

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Out of clock" is American military slang.

It means "out of time".

> It's unfair, wrong and punishes people who prioritized the mission
> over family, or didn't meet their person yet. For those who reach
> mandatory retirement and "*run out of clock*" to obligate service, it
> takes an option for their future plans off the table.

From [Don't Penalize Service Members Who Don't Have Kids. Let Them Bank Their GI Bill Benefits](https://www.military.com/daily-news/opinions/2023/02/15/dont-penalize-service-members-who-dont-have-kids-let-them-bank-their-gi-bill-benefits.html)